# TypeError: Cannot call method 'emit' of undefined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When I am trying to run my nodejs app I am getting below error. I am making a chat app. 
Here is my code :

```
var users = {};
var sockets = {};
var connect = require('connect');
var io = require('socket.io');

var fs = require('fs');

var port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || process.env['app.port'] || 3000;

var app = connect().use(connect.static('public')).listen(port);

var chat_room = io.listen(app);

chat_room.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.emit('entrance', {message: 'Welcome to the chat room!'});
    // Register your client with the server, providing your username
    socket.on('init', function(username) {
        users[username] = socket.id;    // Store a reference to your socket ID
        sockets[socket.id] = { username : username, socket : socket };  // Store a reference to your socket

    });

    socket.on('chat', function(data) {

        user = data.message.user;
        message = data.message.message;

        chat_room.sockets[users[user]].emit(
            'chat', 
            { 
                message : message,
                from : sockets[socket.id].username
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Entire error :

```
> TypeError: Cannot call method 'emit' of undefined
>     at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\private-chat\app.js:35:40)
>     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit [as $emit] (events.js:96:17)
>     at SocketNamespace.handlePacket (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\private-chat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:335:22)
>     at Manager.onClientMessage (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\private-chat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\manager.js:487:38)
>     at WebSocket.Transport.onMessage (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\private-chat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\transport.js:387:20)
>     at Parser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\private-chat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\transports\websocket\hybi-16.js:39:10)
>     at Parser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
>     at opcodeHandlers.1.finish (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\private-chat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\transports\websocket\hybi-16.js:288:16)
>     at Parser.opcodeHandlers.1.expectData [as expectHandler] (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\private-chat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\transports\websocket\hybi-16.js:299:15)
>     at Parser.add (C:\Users\Niraj\Desktop\node\private-chat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\transports\websocket\hybi-16.js:466:24)
```

I am just a beginner in nodejs, is something wrong with my code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of emitting, do a broadcast:

```
socket.broadcast.emit(msg)
```

Comment: but I am getting error on this code `chat_room.sockets[users[user]].emit(`

Comment: I tried `chat_room.sockets[users[user]].send` and also `chat_room.sockets[users[user]].broadcast.emit` both giving me errors

Comment: Broadcast  is send for all client not one user, its not real answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send a message to an unidentified socket.

Don't know the rest of your application, but on:

```
user = data.message.user;
```

shouldn't you be calling "data.message.username" instead of "data.message.user"? Could be different things.